# quickest way to change multi-segment item (ie. IP address) in VI

Tags: vi

in VI, if I want to change one IP address in a file, what's the quickest way?

I could do a global replace (although sometimes the "." will match any character, but it's seldom an issue) or I could just "x" to delete the first 3 octets and then do "cw" to change the last octate and  the new IP.

is there a better way?

Comment: Please, give an example of possible input and output files. You say _I could just "x" to delete the first 3 octets and then do "cw" to change the last octate and the new IP_. Ok, but what is your intent? You say _I want to change one IP address in a file_. Ok, but what is the rational of the change? Do you want to change all octets? Only the first? Only the last? Please, clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

For example, iplist contains the following

```
192.168.1.23
120.121.122.123
120.120.12.1
168.1.2.34
```

To change 120.121.122.123 to 120.121.122.124

```
:1,$s/120\.121\.122\.123/120.121.122.124/g
```

This will globally replace the mentioned IP to new IP ending with 124

Comment: thanks Ronald. to change one IP address (assuming all 4 octets have changed), that's more typing than just doing something like "15x" then "cw<paste>".  that's a great command, but is there something like "4cw<paste>" or some way to use "cw" that ignores the periods (dots) between octets ?

Comment: @ScottT, if you want to match only a single one IP address out of all possible IPs, then you cleary have to match it literaly, as @RonaldPoon does with his command, which is long by definition of "I want to match that specific IP only". If you were to use `:1,$s/\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+\.\d\+/111.111.111.111/g` (which is even longer, actually!) you would match all IPs.

Comment: thanks everyone. maybe i didn't explain it properly. I'm not trying to "match" anything. I don't want to do a "replace". I'd like to figure out how to change a single instance of an IP adress like I would change a hostname. if I've got the new hostname in the buffer, I'd do "cw<shift-insert>" to paste the new hostname over the old one. I want to do that with an IP address.